# MoveIt! Access the pose of a CollisionObject

Tags: ros, moveit, collision, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need to perform transformations between all objects manipulated by the robot. So I intended to create a thread to publish a tf::Transform at the center of each CollisionObject at, say, 50Hz. But to do that I need to access the pose of the collision objects in real time with respect to some frame (base_link for instance). Is this pose published somewhere in a topic, accessible through a service or is present in some field?

I am the one defining the initial position of all CollisionObject and asking the robot to take/leave this object, so thanks to the position of the end effector I could update my own copy of the pose but:

1. This value is necessarily known by MoveIt! to display the objects
2. It's annoying to wonder when the pose has or has not changed
3. If I do it the pose would be duplicated with the internal value of MoveIt!

Another question: is the field frame_id of a CollisionObject used by MoveIt?
I would like to anchor an object (e.g. a cup of tea) to another (e.g. a tray) and ask the robot to manipulate the tray (with moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject.lik_name = end effector of the robot). The goal is obiously to keep the cup fastened to the tray. I wanted to set the frame_id of the cup to the tray like I would so with a regular RViz marker for that but apparently this field is not used, the two CollisionObjects are not linked. Any clue to achieve this goal?

Many thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173590/moveit!-access-the-pose-of-a-collisionobject/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could subscribe to the "monitored_planning_scene" topic (which is what the RVIZ plugins do). This will publish the current planning scene, which includes *changes* to collision objects and attached objects. There is also a service call which you can you use to get the initial state of the planning scene since the published topic includes only diffs.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-06-16**:
Thanks I that is what I do now it works.
Also I added a new question related to these frames.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-06-16**:
As for the frames, yes the frame is used, but I believe (unless it has been recently fixed) you can only use frames which are part of the robot as the RobotState class doesn't track the poses of non-robot frames. I think you will have to attach both objects to the end effector.

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-06-27**:
That's what I did in the end yes. Thanks